# How to catch Exception from IO and print its error.

Tags: haskell

I'd like to catch exceptions from the IO and inspect what kind of exception was raised with `typeOf` and then use the specific exception to pattern match in order to handle the exception specifically. But the following code doesn't work as I expected.

```
import Control.Exception (SomeException, handle)
import Data.Typeable (typeOf)
import System.Environment (getEnv)

main :: IO ()
main = handle missingEnv exe
  where
    exe = do
      env <- getEnv "MISSING_ENV"
      print env
      file <- readFile "/file-does-not-exist"
      print file

missingEnv :: SomeException -> IO ()
missingEnv e = do
  print e
  print $ typeOf e
  return ()
```

The above code will print the following error, but it only shows "SomeException", which doesn't have the specific name for the type of the Exception.

```
MISSING_ENV: getEnv: does not exist (no environment variable)
SomeException
```

You might suggest me to use `lookupEnv`, but that's not my point, because I'd like to learn how to catch an exception, rather than how to avoid an exception.

Is it possible to inspect the specific "type" of a raised exception from `IO`?

Also is it possible to inspect the specific "type" of a raised exception from `MonadError`?

Comment: Is `fromException :: SomeException -> Maybe e` enough for your purposes?

Comment: A good portion (but not all) of exceptions that one might encounter and might want to catch are `IOException`s. It is good to remember that there are `IOException`-specific fucntions in `System.IO.Error` that can be used to further classify those exceptions http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-IO-Error.html#g:2 and extract information from them http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-IO-Error.html#g:3

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can inspect the type of the exception:

```
logSomeException :: SomeException -> IO ()
logSomeException (SomeException e) = print (typeOf e)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solves my problem. Just to check is it possible that an exception is not a `SomeExcpetion`, which will cause the pattern matching fail?

Comment: I had to look it up.  [The docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#g:3) say "It is possible to catch all exceptions, by using the type SomeException".  The next section, on when & when not to do this, is also good.

Answer (score 2):

You've subverted the entire exception-type-matching mechanism by using `SomeException`. If you want to handle a specific kind of exception, just do that, don't convert into and out of `SomeException` along the way. For example:

```
import Control.Exception (IOException, handle, throwIO)
import System.Environment (getEnv)
import System.IO.Error (isDoesNotExistError)

main :: IO ()
main = handle missingEnv exe
  where
    exe = do
      env <- getEnv "MISSING_ENV"
      print env
      file <- readFile "/file-does-not-exist"
      print file

missingEnv :: IOException -> IO ()
missingEnv e | isDoesNotExistError = print e
             | otherwise = throwIO e
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. However, the problem was not how to handle IOException, but how to know what was the exception. If i know the exception that getEnv would throw is IOException, then i would also know how to handle it. IO can throw different kind of exceptions, the document of getEnv isn't clear what kind would throw, so I need a way to be able to inspect.

Comment: Another question: since both getEnv and readFile throws IOException, how to distinguish them?

Comment: @LeoZhang Really? [My copy of the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-Environment.html#v:getEnv) is very clear about which exception it can throw (and is what I used to write my example code above). To distinguish exceptions from different actions, just make the scope of your handler smaller; compare `handle f (getEnv "foo" >> readFile "foo")` with `handle f (getEnv "foo") >> handle g (readFile "foo")` -- in the former `f` doesn't know whether its exception came from `getEnv` or `readFile`, but in the latter it does.